# jquery live method when clicked function

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

If I click on a row in a gridview with .Live method, it opens the dialog by the collapse of the line. If I click the second time I no longer find the image.
How can I do?

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="mGridNoAlign"   PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr">
    <Columns>    
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Giorno" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-CssClass="Giorno" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" Visible="true" HeaderText="Giorno" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Immagine" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="img-responsive">                                        
                <asp:Image ID="img" CssClass="PathImmagine" runat="server" src='<%#Eval("PathImmagine")%>' Width="208px"/>                              
                </div>                                                                          
            </ItemTemplate>                                   
        </asp:TemplateField>                                                                                                
     </Columns>                           
</asp:GridView>

 <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
    Giorno:<span id="giorno"></span><br />
    Gruppo:<span id="gruppo"></span><br />
    Esercizio:<span id="esercizio"></span><br />
    Immagine:<span id="pathimmagine"></span>                            
</div> 


    <script type="text/javascript">      
        $(".Giorno").live("click", function() {
        $("#giorno").html($(".Giorno", $(this).closest("tr")).html());              

$("#pathimmagine").html($(".PathImmagine",$(this).closest("tr")).html('src', 'PathImmagine'));

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "Scheda Allenamento",
            buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");


        }
                    }

                    });         
                    return false;
             });
    </script>
```

Comment: Why `.live()`, ? Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: To expand on the above, `live()` is incredibly outdated, to the point where it no longer exists in the latest versions of jQuery. If you're using anything less than 1.12 you should upgrade

Comment: Because with the bind method, and click on does not work
With .Live instead I open the dialog and it works but after I clicked not charging me the picture